# Ask with replacingAll()

Tags: java

I want to replace all signs of `[FileName]` to `<FileName>` in my file. Any ideas and clues are wellcome. I'm a beginner so please be patient to me.

Here is my code:

```
public class TextFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextFormatter tf = new TextFormatter();
        File f = new File("D:\\Temp.txt");
        try {
            tf.replaceInFile(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void replaceInFile(File file) throws IOException {

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

        Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while(br.ready()) {
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("[", "<"));
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("]", ">"));
        }

        fw.close();
        br.close();
        fr.close();

        // Finally replace the original file.
        tempFile.renameTo(file);
    }
}
```

I've got error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at TextFormatter.replaceInFile(TextFormatter.java:36)
at TextFormatter.main(TextFormatter.java:19)
```

line 36 is

```
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("]", ">"));
```

and line 19 is

```
tf.replaceInFile(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

`br.readLine()` reads a line, every time it's called. So if you want to replace `[` and `]` in the same line, you shouldn't call `readLine()` twice (and you shouldn't call `fw.write()` twice either).

And `ready()` is not what you should use. Simply read each line until `readLine()` returns null:

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replace("[", "<");
    line = line.replace("]", ">");
    fw.write(line);
}
```

Also, I guess you want to keep the line separators. So you should wrap the FileWriter into a PrintWriter and use `println()`.

Finally, you should make sure to close the reader and the writer, whatever happens in the method. Use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) JavaDoc, this function returns

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Therefore, you should check each call to `br.readLine()` to make sure it's not `null` before attempting to do something with it...such as

```
  fw.write(br.readLine().replace("]", ">"));
           ^  ^ 
This is null..so attempting this throws a `NullPointerException`
```

But even more of a problem, is that you are incorrectly reading in a new line, when you are intending to make a second replacement on the *same line*. Changing it to this addresses both issues:

```
String line = br.readLine();
if(line != null)  {
    fw.write(line.replace("[", "<"));
    fw.write(line.replace("]", ">"));
}
```